# Legend in not mapping linetype when geom_errorbar is used

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the data:

```
enter code here

group <- rep(c("a", "b"), each=10)
res <- c(sample(20:30,10,T),sample(60:80,10,T) )
sd <- rnorm(20,2)
t <-  rep(1:10,2)
df <- data.frame(t=t,group=group, res=res, sd=sd)
```

From that I want this plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=t, y=res, 
                     group=group, 
                     colour=group, 
                     shape=group ), linetype="solid")+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=res-sd, ymax=res+sd))+
  geom_line(aes(linetype=group))
```

**The problem:**
The legend is NOT mapping the aesthetics *linetype*. 
It is doing correctly for *shape* and *colour*.

I also tried setting the *linetype* as overall mapping and *linetype="solid"* in *geom_errorbar*, but the result was the same. See code bellow.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=t, y=res, 
               group=group, 
               colour=group, 
               shape=group, 
               linetype=group))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=res-sd, ymax=res+sd), linetype="solid")+
  geom_line()
```

For obvious reasons I don't want errorbars with different line types. 
The reason for this many mappings to the same variable is to make it beautifull on screen and black an white print friendly.

How can I do this plot and have the legend mapping the linetype too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=t, y=res, 
               group=group, 
               colour=group, 
               shape=group, 
               linetype=group))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=res-sd, ymax=res+sd, 
                    linetype = NULL)) + #remove the mapping
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Thank you! Simple and exactly what I needed.